# Java URL Decoder not working as expected

Tags: java, url, urldecode

I have a simple program which tries to decode an encoded URL. But for some reason this doesn't seem to be working. Would anybody have any idea why this is happening? I have spent hours but haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is the program:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class DecodeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String encodedUrl = "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWUuY29tL3dlYi9teWFjY291bnQvYWNjb3VudF9ob21lLmpzcA";
    String decodedUrl = "";

    try {
        decodedUrl = URLDecoder.decode(encodedUrl, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("String: " + decodedUrl);
    }
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
 String: aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYWUuY29tL3dlYi9teWFjY291bnQvYWNjb3VudF9ob21lLmpzcA
```

This is the same encoded string.

Comment: There's nothing to decode in that string. Try throwing in some plus (`+`) characters or byte values with something like (`%32`).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you sure you don't need a base64 decoder? this is the expect result. URL encoding/decoding is something like transforming spaces in %20 and stuff like that

```
%0D%0AGood+luck%28you%27ll+need+it%29
```

into

```
Good luck (you'll need it)
```

base64 decoding will give you

```
https://www.ae.com/web/myaccount/account_home.jsp
```

for your input

Comment: Thanks for the response! You are right - I would need to use base64 decoding. How would I go about doing it in java?

Answer (score 4):

The string you are sending is not URL encoded, so it can't be decoded. Where did you get the string?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing exactly what it's supposed to. There is nothing to change.